# Warning to disable GPS on Android

Tags: android, gps, warnings

In my android app, the user is able to turn off the GPS.

Because I need sometimes of the GPS and I want also ask the user to turn on the GPS again.

But the user is able to mark for not appears more this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) which has the method [onProviderDisabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onProviderDisabled%28java.lang.String%29). This method gets called everytime the user turns off the GPS provided you have set the Location Provider to be GPS.